ASP.NET Framework publish error - the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
I have an old .asmx Web Service build with ASP.NET Framework-4.8
It runs and builds fine, but when I wanted to publish the application, I got this error:

Publish has encountered an error. Build failed. Check the Output
window for more details
.vs\MyAppWebService\FileContentIndex\a9a02950-10cb-45ea-8c13-4b182877647c.vsidx
to
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\MyAppWebService--676085791\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.vs\MyAppWebService\FileContentIndex\a9a02950-10cb-45ea-8c13-4b182877647c.vsidx
failed. The process cannot access the file
'.vs\MyAppWebService\FileContentIndex\a9a02950-10cb-45ea-8c13-4b182877647c.vsidx'
because it is being used by another process.

I closed the application several times, and also restarted the system, but the issue still remains.
I can't even find release and clean solution on the Visual Studio. I suppose may be because it is ASP.NET Framework-4.8

Don't know anything about this exact issue, but I would check first with process explorer that what process is locking the file.
